# full text search and date field

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino, full-text-search

I have problem with full text search for one application.

I cannot search for dates for a field that is defined as date/time. The full text search dialog for Condition "By field" and the field in question give us the option "contains/does not contain" when we instead want the search options "is on/is after" etc.

-> delete and re-create FTI does not work

-> run off line copy style compact

-> Creating local new copy (design and documents), and creating full text
index, will enable searching by date for this field.

-> but this does not work on production server

Any ideas?

Comment: Other problem could be, that there is still a document with this Datetime field set as Text in your application.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an issue with the UNK table. The field was probably not created as a date/time field in the first place. Delete the FT index, do an offline compact, and re-build the FT index.

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21261002 for more info.

Comment: -> delete the index and delete the associated FT directory then run
compact -D on it and recreate the index solved the problem

Title: How to Delete and Create the Full Text Index
Doc #: 1092508
URL: http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21092508

this actually solved the problem

Comment: but now i have run into another problem #2
it possible to search the field as a Date/Time field, but the search options are
still "contains/does not contain"

any ideas ? thanks for your help

Comment: It sounds like the UNK table hasn't been re-built. Did you run the compact offline using ncompact? Where do you see that the field is now a Date/Time field?